# Why does Google index a URL with UTM parameters when the canonical URL does not include them?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, rel-canonical, utm-parameters

I've noticed some strange behavior in the search results, where Google includes only the "duplicated" landing page in the search results. Searchmetrics website status then also picks up this page, but the original page is ignored.

- There are no "nofollow"
- Canonical is setup to point to the right page
- The search results shows the page with UTM parameters (though Google should ignore these?)
- Searchmetrics shows URL with UTM-parameters because of search result
- There is one internal link that has the same UTM-parameter (points to sub-domain with same UTM)

Still Google indexes `?utm_source=...` Why?

Comment: Does this [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/101851/1463) help?